# Group by user, location and date range in YII Framework

Tags: mysql, web-applications, yii, grouping, date-range

Can someone help me on how to use the date range (create_date) and grouping the data by user_id and location?

I input the field user_id, location and daterange, sorting results just happened to date range.
I tried many times to fix the controller, but the outcome remains the same.

If I just input the the user_id field and input the location and no date range field sorting on CGridView only by user_id and the location, date range remains in random order.

Below is a model,controller and view

**Model**
**my variable in model**

```
 public $from_date;
 public $to_date;
      ....
 public function search()
        {
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;


            $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
            $criteria->compare('location',$this->location,true);
            $criteria->compare('satisfy_val',$this->satisfy_val,true);
            $criteria->compare('create_date',$this->create_date,true);
            /* $criteria->mergeWith($this->dateRangeSearchCriteria('create_date',$this->create_date
            )); */
            if(!empty($this->from_date) && empty($this->to_date)){
                $criteria->condition="create_date >= '$this->from_date'";
            }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && empty($this->from_date)){
                $criteria->condition="create_date <= '$this->to_date'";
            }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && !empty($this->from_date)){
                $criteria->condition="create_date >= '$this->from_date' and create_date<= '$this->to_date'";
            }

            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>array('user_id DESC','create_date DESC')),
            ));
        }
```

**This is my controller**

```
public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Satisfact('search');
        /* $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values */
        if(isset($_GET['Satisfact'])){
            /* $model->attributes=$_GET['Satisfact']; */
            $model->user_id=$_GET['Satisfact']['user_id'];
            $model->lokasi=$_GET['Satisfact']['location'];          
            $model->from_date=$_GET['Satisfact']['from_date'];
            $model->to_date=$_GET['Satisfact']['to_date'];

        }
            $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));


    }
...............
```

**and my view**

```
<div class="wide form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method'=>'get',
)); ?>



    <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->label($model,'user_id'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'user_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
        <?php $_u = User::model()->findAll();
                  echo CHtml::activeDropDownList(
                        $model,'user_id',
                        CHtml::listData($_u,'id','username'),
                        array('prompt'=>'',) //empty is aliases FOR ALL user
                    );
               ?>
    </div>
    <div="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'location'); ?>
        <?php $lo_u = Location::model('Location')->findAll('id');
                  echo CHtml::activeDropDownList(
                        $model,'location',
                        CHtml::listData($lo_u,'location','location'),
                        array('prompt'=>'',)
                    );
               ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->label($model,'location'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'create_date'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'create_date'); ?>
        <?php 
        echo "From : ";
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
            array(
            'name'=>'Satisfact[from_date]',
            'options'=>array('dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',),            

            ));
        echo " To : ";
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
            array(
            'name'=>'Satisfact[to_date]',
            'options'=>array('dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',),            

            )); 


        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
if(!empty($this->from_date) && empty($this->to_date)){
                $criteria->condition="create_date >= '$this->from_date'";
            }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && empty($this->from_date)){
                $criteria->condition="create_date <= '$this->to_date'";
            }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && !empty($this->from_date)){
                $criteria->condition="create_date >= '$this->from_date' and create_date<= '$this->to_date'";
            }
```

In above code `$this->from_date` is an attribute and you are using it as a string because you are putting commas around it.

```
'$this->from_date'
```

above line is wrong in your code because you can see commas in it.

try

```
$criteria->condition="create_date >=". $this->from_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

For date ranges in MySQL you should use the BETWEEN function.

```
 $criteria->condition= "create_date between '$this->from_date' and '$this->to_date'"
```

You should set the defaults of from_date & to_date if nothing is set so you can always just go with the one condition.

In your criteria you are using             `$criteria->compare('satisfy_val',$this->satisfy_val,true);` 
Though this is never handled as input from the form? I'd try and just get data based off of the dates first and ensure that part of your criteria is working.

On a side note what you're doing is usually achieved in Yii via the CGridView widget.

Comment: for while satisfy_val field is not used, the problem of grouping the data, has been resolved.
i was try your criteria condition and input from_date: 2015-02-21 to_date:2015-02-28. search results only the date 2015-02-21 until 2015-02-27, data 2015-02-28 is not appear